# If else condition in addition. Defining the range

Tags: shell

I want to write a program which can add two numbers. 
The program should contain the if else condition which can describe the range of numbers.

This is what i have done so far:

```
Echo"enter two numbers "
Read num1 num2
Sum=$((num1 + num2)) 
Echo" The sum is = $sum"
```

Comment: what have you tryed so far

Comment: I am done with the addition but dont know how to define range..... Like the no. Should be in the range (0-9)

Comment: Using if else condition

Comment: Add your code please

Comment: That addition program i have written?

Comment: Yes and mabye you should also mention which language you are using

Comment: Echo "enter two numbers"

Comment: Edit your question and add it to it please

Comment: I am writing in vim editor

Comment: Echo"enter two numbers " Read num1 num2 Sum=$((num1 + num2)) Echo" The sum is = $sum"

Comment: Why are the first characters of every line in Caps? Won't that break the shell script?

Comment: There should be a space between echo and the quote.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, your problems were all typographical errors.

```
echo "enter two numbers "
read num1 num2
if [ $num1 -lt 0 ] ; then
    echo num1 out of range
    exit
fi
if [ $num2 -lt 0 ] ; then
    echo num2 out of range
    exit
fi

sum=$((num1 + num2))
echo " The sum is = $sum"
```